# Store credentials for gems server

Tags: ruby, bundler

I have a private gem server protected by http basic authentication. Currently, I'm storing the credentials as environment variables and have this line at the top of my Gemfile:

```
source "https://#{ENV['GEMS_USERNAME']}:#{ENV['GEMS_PASSWORD']}@gems.myserver.com"
```

So far so good, and when I run bundle everything seems to work. But than I looked at the generated Gemfile.lock and noticed that the credentials for my server got hardcoded there.

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  remote: https://username:password@gems.myserver.com/
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I don't want to push my credentials into the git repo.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bundler >= 1.6 you can simply do something like this:

```
bundle config http://gems.myserver.com username:password
```

And it should put those credentials in your **.bundle/config** file so you don't need to explicitly include them on your Gemfile(.lock) anymore.

Comment: For the record, I couldn't find any documentation for this, only the [pull request](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/2825)...

Comment: I am on Bundler 1.6.2 and am still seeing this behavior. Is there no way to prevent the lock file from storing the credentials?

Comment: You need 1.6.4 at least, check the changelog at https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#164-2014-07-17

Comment: I believe this will set the bundle config locally as in `.bundle/config` in your current Gemfile folder, but if you need it machine wide it's `bundle config set --global url.com user:password`.